# What is the http://go2.wordpress.com/ redirect?

Tags: url, redirects

Hi I see a [wordpress.com](http://openunionism.wordpress.com/) blog and on the latest post there is a redirect for the external links via "http://go2.wordpress.com/" redirect. This redirect is obfuscated - on hovering the link it displays a "http://google.com/url?..." redirect instead.

What is this and why is it suddenly on this post and not others?

Also, would it harm SEO for the affected outgoing links?

Answer (score 1):

It is for a skimlinks ad service they are running. Users who upgrade are redirected immediately. Check the following [discussion](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/link-redirection-through-go2wordpresscom). You will also find it in the source

`<script type="text/javascript">
    var skimlinks_pub_id = "725X1342";
    var skimlinks_sitename = 'openunionism.wordpress.com';
    var skimlinks_domain = "go2.wordpress.com";
    skimlinks();
</script>`

Check [skimlinks](http://www.skimlinks.com/) fore more info.

Comment: what are the SEO implications for these 302 redirects in terms of the affected target urls?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't done much research on SEO, much less the implications these redirects would have on the affected urls (in this case). Perhaps John or someone more knowledgeable than me could shed some light on this matter.